# C++11 rvalue and move: Can legacy code avoid copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, call-by-value

Please understand that I'm still learning the concepts of C++11's move and rvalue semantics. My question is whether legacy code can get a free lunch of avoiding unnecessary copy by simply using C++11 compilers and STL.

Here is a very simple example. This code builds a simple character frequency table for a given string. For example, "apple" should return `{('a', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 1), ('p', 2)}`. As you will see, I'm just using vectors as values.

```
typedef std::tuple<char, int> Frequency;
typedef std::vector<Frequency> Frequencies;

Frequencies buildFrequenciesTable(std::string w) {
  char table['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0, };
  std::for_each(w.cbegin(), w.cend(), [&table](char c) {
    ++table[::tolower(c) - 'a'];
  });

  Frequencies freqs;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 'z' - 'a' + 1; ++i) {
    if (table[i] != 0)
      freqs.push_back(tuple<char, int>((char) ('a' + i), table[i]));
  }
  return freqs; // Q1: Is vector get copied?
}

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  Frequencies f1 = buildFrequenciesTable("apple"); // Q2: Copy?
  Frequencies f2 = buildFrequenciesTable("banana");
  vector<Frequencies> fs = { f1, f2 }; // Q3: Copy?
}
```

It is clear that C++03 generates all copy code (using copy constructors and assignment operators) when returning vectors as value. What about in C++11? `std::vector` a has move constructor. Can this code get avoid any unnessarry copies? Or, should I use either `&&` or `std::forward` in the above code?

I tried to debug the internal STL code, but it was hard to convince.

Note: My goal is to minimize any unnecessary copies in these functions. I know I could use new/pointers/references, but this will need to resolve memory leak problem. So, I'd like to use values as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Q1, there is most likely no copy even in C++03 as the copy is removed by the "Named Return Value Optimization" (NRVO).

For Q2, there is also most likely no copy even in C++03 as copy-elision removes it.

For Q3, even in C++11 you *do* have copies as you would need to mark `f1` and `f2` as movable in order to actually have them moved:

```
vector<Frequencies> fs = { std::move(f1), std::move(f2) };
```

Since you asked multiple question I think I will omit further explanations, look up NRVO, copy-elision and where `std::move` is required, ask if you have any further questions.

However, there are cases where you would get free moves, for example if there is a temporary which could be moved:

```
vector<Frequencies> fs = { buildFrequenciesTable("apple"),
                           buildFrequenciesTable("bananas") };
```

The above would detect the two vectors returned from `buildFrequenciesTable()` as temporaries and therefore they will be moved into `fs`.

Comment: Thank you! So, basically, in the case of Q1 and Q2, there are nothing benefits from C++11's r-value references and move semantics? Am I correctly understood?

Comment: My goal is actually to minimize any unnecessary copies in these functions. I know I could use new/pointers/references, but this will require crazy leak problem. So, I'd like to use values as much as possible.

Comment: One more sub questions (could be stupid question): Can I do even more optimize this code? For example, returning `Frequencies&&` in `buildFrequenciesTable`, or declaring `Frequencies&& f1` or so. In particular, `f1` and `f2` in the above won't be modified.

Comment: @Nullptr Q1 and Q2 are optimal given that the RVO/NRVO and copy-elision kick in. While this might not be guaranteed, it is something that in my experience works quite reliably. In case of doubt, you need to check it, though. I would advise not to fiddle with `Frequencies&` or `Frequencies&&` as it makes the code less clear (IMHO) and it is only required in special situations. But if you are concerned about performance, knowledge (and experience!) with copy-elision and RVO/NRVO is essential and something you should really look into.

Comment: ...except that you used the initializer list constructor of vector which does not care about movability. `std::initializer_list<T>` and move don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

Returning the vector from the function (`Q1`) will use move semantics where possible, without needing to modify the code. Likewise initialising the vectors from the returned temporary (`Q2`) will use move semantics; the return value is an *rvalue*, so can be moved from. In practice, both moves (or, historically, copies) should be elided, so that the function initialises `f1` and `f2` directly with no moving or copying.

Putting them in the vector (`Q3`) does require copying: variables are *lvalues*, which can't be implicitly moved. So you would have to use `std::move`, or restructure the code, to avoid these copies.